# I think my code is all correct but it does not work

Tags: c++

I coded this to show me this:

> 1  + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + … + (1/n!)
>  
>   if ( n < 10 )

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int n;
float factn=1,m,sum;
cout<<"enter n\n";
cin>>n;
if(n<10&&n>=0){
do{
        factn=factn*n;
        m=1/factn;
        sum=sum+m;
        n--;
    }while(n>=1);
        cout<<sum;
}
else{
    cout<<"error!\n";
}
return 0;

}
```

This code must show this:

> ( n < 10 )      1  + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + … + (1/n!)

What is the problem?
It returns wrong values :(

Comment: "i think my code is all correct" is usually a sign of incorrect code.

Comment: In addition to the comments about your initial sum value your factorial calculation is incorrect, say n is 5 then you get (whatever value is in sum at the start) + 1/5 + 1/20 + 1/60 + 1/120 + 1/120.  You need to calculate the factorial for n an each iteration of the loop.  Your result should be (0 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/24 + 1/120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized sum=0 in the beginning. The variable sum, has a random value, that is stored in Ram at that location in memory where sum should be.

Comment: Why would the value of `sum` be stored in the same place as `m`? That's not the case. They are different variables.

Comment: @Rakete1111 what? no it isn't

Comment: @Swift I know, that's why I'm asking. I should have phrased my question better :)

Comment: @Swift @Francois Rakete1111 is referring to the line in the answer `The variable sum, has a random value, that is stored in Ram at that place in memory where m should be.`  You're all saying the same thing...

Comment: I meant sum. I was doing something else and was distracted. Initializing sum=0 should work

Comment: @Tuffwet I had read that "place" is the ram. That could be typo or a  clearly a style error made by a person for whom  English isn't native (e.g. translated directly, it is correct statement in my native language)

Comment: This is not the only problem with the code. See the comment in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in the code. First, `sum` is not initialized, so whatever result comes out won't have any meaning. Second, the loop goes the wrong way. To calculate successive factorials it has to start with 1, then move to 2, then 3, etc.; this loop starts at `n`, then moves to `n-1`, then `n-2`, etc. Change that `do... while` loop to look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // do the calculation for i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take time to fix your formatting. Aside from making code pretty and readable, it often got that effect on  focusing your thoughts on the  structure and logic of program. Probably you could  spot the problem with formula implementation in that case.

cin can give you status if entered value is correct. There is more, if you want repeat  input,  i.e. the status should be cleared.
Your formula can be implemented with for() loop, using local variables. It doesn't really matter which type of loop you use, you can use a direct declaration and use  while if you want,  just for()  allows some declarations and statements included into its "header":

```
#include <iostream>
using  std::cin;
using  std::cout;
int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "enter n\n";
    bool res = cin >> n;  // false if input was incorrectly parsed
    if (res) 
        res = (n<10) && (n>=0);

    if( res )
    {
        float sum = 1; // starting value for sum
        for( int k = 1, j = 1; k < n; k++)
        {
            j = j * (j + 1);  // j accumulates factorial
            sum = sum + 1.f / j;
        }
        cout<< sum << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"error!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Actually there is way to calculate factorial without cycle at all, by using exponential functions.